# Junit DirtiesContext is not rollbacking my transcation using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, junit, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have create delete method in my repo class and did use @Transactional at class level,

When I call deletebyID its deleting that id. in Junit I did use DirtiesContext it should roll back the transaction, but due to @Transactional at class level, it commuted my delete (It did what suppose to do),

now my juint not able to rollback that transaction.

How to overcome this issue?

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CourseRepository {

@Autowired
EntityManager em;

public Course findById(Long id) {
    return em.find(Course.class, id);
}

public Course deleteById(Long id) {
    Course course= em.find(Course.class, id);
    em.remove(course);
    return course;
  }
}
```

In my Junit

```
@Autowired
CourseRepository courseRepo;
@Test
@DirtiesContext
public void deleteById_basicTest() {
    courseRepo.deleteById(100001L);
    assertNull(courseRepo.findById(100001L));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @Transactional for each test case. It will rollbacks transactions.
It works.

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void deleteById_basicTest() {
    courseRepo.deleteById(100001L);
    assertNull(courseRepo.findById(100001L));
}
```